# Mount EFS to wp-content on elastic beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So i'm having a problem setting up a Wordpress site on EB. I got the EFS to mount correctly on wp-content/uploads/wpfiles (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html) however this only allows the pages to be stored and not the plugins. Is it possible to mount the entire wp-content folder onto EFS, I've tried and so far failed

Comment: Maybe a timeout issue, as EFS has very slow write/ read operations. Increase timeout or mount s3 bucket on your instance to have better performance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this issue was resolved and it passed silently. I'm having the same issue as you, but with a different error. My knowledge is fairly limited so take what I say with a grain of salt, according to what I saw in your log the problem is that your instance can't see the server. I think that it could be that your EB application is getting deployed in a different Availability Zone than your EFS. What I mean is that maybe you have mount targets for AZ a, b and d and your EB is getting deployed in AZ c. I hope this helps.

I tried a different approach (it basically does the same thing, but I'm manually linking each of the subfolders instead of the wp-content folder), for it to work I deleted the original folders inside `/var/app/ondeck` (that will eventually get copied to `/var/app/current/` that is the folder which get served). Of course, once this gets done your Wordpress won't work since it doesn't have any themes, the solution here would be to quickly log in to the EC2 instance in which your ElasticBeanstalk app is running and manually copying the contents to the mounted EFS (in my case the `/wpfiles` folder). To connect to the EC2 instance (you can find the instance ID under your EB health configuration) you can follow [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html) and to mount your EFS you can follow [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html). Of course, if the config works you won't have to mount it since it would be already mounted though empty. Here is the content of my config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    EFS_NAME: '`{"Ref" : "FileSystem"}`'
    MOUNT_DIRECTORY: '/wpfiles'
    REGION: '`{"Ref": "AWS::Region"}`'

packages:
  yum:
    nfs-utils: []
    jq: []

files:
  "/tmp/mount-efs.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      mkdir -p $MOUNT_DIRECTORY
      EFS_REGION=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.REGION')
      EFS_NAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.EFS_NAME')
      MOUNT_DIRECTORY=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.MOUNT_DIRECTORY')
      mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $EFS_NAME.efs.${EFS_REGION}.amazonaws.com:/ $MOUNT_DIRECTORY || true
      mkdir -p $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/uploads
      mkdir -p $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/plugins
      mkdir -p $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/themes
      chown webapp:webapp -R $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/uploads
      chown webapp:webapp -R $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/plugins
      chown webapp:webapp -R $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/themes

commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "/tmp/mount-efs.sh"
container_commands:
  01-rm-wp-content-uploads:
    command: rm -rf /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads && rm -rf /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/plugins  && rm -rf /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/themes
  02-symlink-uploads:
    command: ln -snf $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/uploads /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/uploads && ln -snf $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/plugins /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/plugins && ln -snf $MOUNT_DIRECTORY/themes /var/app/ondeck/wp-content/themes
```

I'm using another config file to create my EFS as in [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-php-wordpress/blob/master/.ebextensions/efs-create.config), in case you have already created your EFS you must change `` EFS_NAME: '`{"Ref" : "FileSystem"}`' `` to `EFS_NAME: id_of_your_EFS`.

I hope this helps [user3738338](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3738338/user3738338).

Comment: By the way, I was able to fix the error by changing the mount point to /var/app/current/wp-content. It probably wasn't able to mount in that specific folder so I changed directly to the final destination of that folder. It gave me a new silent problem since it mounts perfectly, but data doesn't get written there. I'll try a different approach for now

Answer (score -1):

You can do following this link - https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-php-wordpress/blob/master/.ebextensions/efs-mount.config

Just keep a note it uses uploads, you can change it for wp-content.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but whenever I move the mount to wp-content Elastic beanstalk fails to deploy it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste error log? also is you wp-content empty or it has contents. I suggest to manually mount the EFS first and copy the contents to it, then when you redeploy keep the wp-contents folder as blank in your src.

Comment: Would deleting all files in wp-content then changing the command in the github link too "sudo -u webapp ln -s /wpfiles wp-content" work? Here's the logs regarding the EFS https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqe1z0wx01mlvun/LogEFS.txt?dl=0

Comment: You can keep it blank rather then deleting

Comment: But looking at you logs, your efs is not mounting at all, either your security group for EFS is not corrent or might be you didn't have dns and hostname enabled in VPC. The EFS security group should allow NFS rules from web server, also check for DNS and Hostanme enablement in VPC

Comment: Updating DNS Support for Your VPC. You can view and update the DNS support attributes for your VPC using the Amazon VPC console.To describe and update DNS support for a VPC using the console Open the Amazon VPC console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/. In the navigation pane, choose Your VPC. Select the VPC from the list.Review the information in the Summary tab. In this example, both settings are enabled.The DNS Settings tab.To update these settings, choose Actions and either Edit DNS Resolution or Edit DNS Hostnames. In the dialog box that opens, choose Yes or No, and then choose Save.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-create-security-groups.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So DNS solution and DNS hostnames should be yes? They currently are. I think it is setup correctly because if i follow this https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-php-wordpress/blob/master/.ebextensions/efs-mount.config it works fine but whenever I change the directory to that of /wp-content/wp-files it doesn't work

Comment: But the error logs you pasted clearly shows an issue either with security group or vpc dns. Please check your security group for EFS. It should allow inbounds on NFS port from webserver.

Comment: Hey man sorry for not getting back. The reason why I don't believe its a VPC issue is because when i follow the guide correctly it does work as intended however I want it to sync plugins with EFS as well and not just uploads. Heres the logs from following the guide https://www.dropbox.com/s/36gmzqy2v4j5rry/LogEFS2.txt?dl=0